# downloading files outside application root folder on the same server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net applications hosted on the same server. I need to access files uploaded in one application from another. For instance, I have my original files in www.crm.sample.com/ImportedFiles/ and I want to access or download those files from www.gmc.sample.com. How can I achieve it.

Comment: I can come up with two options: (1) hardcode the download location from the first application into your second one (if download location is fixed) or (2) create a web service in your first application, to share (serve) it's downloaded files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with classes in `System.IO` namespace. Create a web page in your app that instead of rendering HTML, sends desired file's bytes to the client:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("d:\\Site1\\img1.jpg");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Reponse.End();
```

you can use `QueryString` to send parameters that show witch file the client wants.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create some virtual folders in IIS on Site 1, which map to the download destination in Site 2. Then by calling `Server.MapPath("~/site2download")` on the virtual folder and using the `System.IO` namespace you can read the files and do whatever you like from there.

[Heres](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) some info on how to create a virtual directory in IIS 7